# Spring Form Validation (JSR-303)

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-form

Getting an error while using validation api. Am validating the input in register.jsp
i have included the required jars.
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar

register.jsp

```
<h4>Register</h4>
<form:form method="post" action="register" modelAttribute="user">
    <form:label path="userName">UserName</form:label>
    <form:input path="userName"/>
    <form:errors path="userName"/><br>
    <form:label path="password">Password</form:label>
    <form:password path="password"/> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form:form>
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usertable")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="username")
    @Size(min=6,max=10,message="Error Message")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
```

When i enter username less than 6,result.hasErrors() is false , but it should be true.
RegisterController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="register")
public class RegisterController {
    @Autowired
    private RegisterService registerService;
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView register(@Valid User user,BindingResult result){
        System.out.println("hi");
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return new ModelAndView("index");
        }
        else{
            if(registerService.register(user))  
                return new ModelAndView("success");
            return new ModelAndView("failure");
        }
    }
    public RegisterService getRegisterService() {
        return registerService;
    }
    public void setRegisterService(RegisterService registerService) {
        this.registerService = registerService;
    }
}
```

RegisterService.java

```
@Service
public class RegisterService {
    @Autowired
    private RegisterDao registerDao;
    @Transactional
    public boolean register(User user){
        registerDao.register(user);
        return true;
    }
    public RegisterDao getRegisterDao() {
        return registerDao;
    }
    public void setRegisterDao(RegisterDao registerDao) {
        this.registerDao = registerDao;
    }
}
```

RegisterDao.java

```
@Repository
public class RegisterDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public boolean register(User user){
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
        return true;
    }
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Am getting this error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/Annotated] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.labs.domain.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Error Message', propertyPath=userName, rootBeanClass=class com.labs.domain.User, messageTemplate='Error Message'}
]] with root cause
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.labs.domain.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Error Message', propertyPath=userName, rootBeanClass=class com.labs.domain.User, messageTemplate='Error Message'}
]
```

Can someone tell me where am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the second needed annotation to the Controller RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView register(@Valid @ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result) {
    ...
}
```

Also, is there a GET Request in which you feed the model with an appropriate User when loading the page initially, before submitting the  ?

Comment: Yes Jeyp, I passesd model addribute to the register.jsp.

Comment: Note that in a default configuration, Adding `@ModelAttribute` or leaving it off is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

After reading spring validation documentation , i got to know that, i have to add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in my spring configuration.